# Can't not update the textbox when clicked the optionmenu

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to display my selection in the optionmenu to the textbox. Could anyone help me with this one?
when I clicked one option in the optionmenu, the textbox didn't update. Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


display_text=StringVar()
e1=Entry(root, textvariable=display_text, width=42)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

def OptionMenu_Select(): 
   display_text.set(var.get())  

Menu = {"Pho bo":"$3.50", "Chao ga":"$3.99", "pho xao":"$4.10", "Com rang":"$3.80"}
choices = [m + "  " + Menu[m] for m in Menu]  

var=StringVar()
var.set(choices[0])  
display_text.set(choices[0]) 
popupMenu = OptionMenu(root, var, *choices, command = OptionMenu_Select)
popupMenu.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the code in a terminal, then you should see there is exception when an item is selected in the option menu:

```
TypeError: OptionMenu_Select() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

It is because the callback of `command` option of `OptionMenu` expects an argument, the selected item, but your function does not have argument.

Just modify the function as below:

```py
def OptionMenu_Select(val):
   #display_text.set(var.get())
   # just use the passed argument
   display_text.set(val)
```